# is there any possibility to link AzureAlerts and Azuredevops workitems?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

is there any automated way to directly create bugs in Azuredevops projects dashboard and assigned to team whenever Aure loganalytic query based alerts triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if the Azure Log Analytics query based alerts can call other services or APIs, then it's possible to create work items by calling the REST API [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). But, there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do this.

However, there's an `Azure Log Analytics` connector in Power Automate. You can try to setup a flow using the `Azure Log Analytics` and `Azure DevOps` connectors in Power Automate. The flow will be triggered when the Azure Log Analytics query based alert is trigged.

You need to call the [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API in flow to create the bug. More information please reference [Add an Attachment in Azure Dev Ops using MS Flow](https://www.fidelityfactory.com/blog/2019/10/14/use-ms-flow-to-add-an-attachment-in-azure-dev-ops-2zfzx) and [Azure DevOps Integration (via Microsoft Power Automate)](https://wiki.easyvista.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/Integration/Azure%20DevOps%20Integration%20-%20Integration%20List/Azure%20DevOps%20via%20Microsoft%20Flow%20Integration/#HCreatetheBugworkitemtype)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great. But Power Automate seems to be another application and we wont get it as a service in azure itself . is that correct ? Is there any feature or service available in Azure itself for this?

Comment: @Vowneee Yeah, it's another service. As far as I know, there isn't a built-in feature to achieve this in Azure itself.

Comment: @Vowneee May I know if the answer helps?

Comment: Yes, You answered it clearly and thank you very much. We are checking if this is possible with any scripts any azure plugins. Because for this requirement alone we cant accommodate Power automate license and costs.